# Regex equivalent to XOR

Tags: regex, xor

I am trying to come up with a regex that would accept any of the values  below combined, except when NONE is present. Something similar to an XOR where if NONE is present nothing else would be accepted, and vice-versa.

This is what I have so far...but it doesn't really enforces the mutual exclusivity of NONE:

(NONE)|((FOO|BAR|SPAM)( ?\| ?(FOO|BAR|SPAM))*)

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Which regex program do you use

Comment: Hi Poul, I am using this regex to filter allowable content on a Splunk dashboard. So far I've been using regex101.com to check my regexes.

Comment: Could you please provide possible strings for processing? It's not clear how is the NONE can be combined (if it can) with other values

Comment: Hi Aleksandr. In this case here the client can enter the category of their product...So the product category could be FOO|BAR or FOO|BAR|SPAM or SPAM but once they enter NONE, meaning that it doesnt fall in any categoy, they wont be allowed to enter any other values. So NONE should always be by itself. I hope I made it a little more clear. Thank you!

Comment: So the whole string is either NONE or one of FOO, BAR, SPAM?

Comment: The selected categories will be separated by a pipe. They can enter one or more categories, but if NONE is entered, nothing else should be accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*NONE)(?:.*(FOO|BAR|SPAM))*
```

It starts by a `negative look ahead` for: any number of any char followed by `'NONE'`.

If this test fails (NONE found) then the match will fail. If no `'NONE'` is found, it moves on and matches: From start of string any number of any char followed by any of your Words. This part is repeated.

`Edit` to allow NONE by itself:

```
^NONE$|^(?!.*NONE)(?:.*(FOO|BAR|SPAM))*
```

It now start by checking if 'NONE' is alone (which is ok).

Comment: No, if NONE is present in the string, it fails.

Comment: How could I change it so it would allow NONE by itself?

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!